# Has gebish site changed?

Tags: geb

For the last couple of days can't access geb site http://www.gebish.org/. Any idea what's going on? Is it being restructured or has URL changed?

Comment: Not sure why down vote. Is it a problem to ask for the details? It's an issue for me as a developer as I can't access the geb book or documentation anymore and hampers my work. Also if you are down voting something, appreciate if a comment is also added on what you think what's wrong with the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so finally after logging an issue with geb came to know that they have lost their dns. Details here - https://github.com/geb/issues/issues/486#issuecomment-305424939

Alternate/temporary URL for the site is http://gebish.herokuapp.com/